# How To Access Repeater's Items Randomly

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, repeater

I have a repeater with an `ItemTemplate` contains a `CheckBox`, `TextBox`

My repeater represents a check list plus a `TextBox` to put a comment to each item I select from the list.

Now, I've a page for editing an existing shopping cart in my database and it uses this repeater to enable the user to update his list. So I need to update the List with the previous selected values from the database. I can't think of a simple logic or way to access only the repeater's items that are on the previous list   ...I'm thinking about trying to access each item that's in my database only instead of looping and looping.

I know It's really confusing so I'll just put it in a more illustrative way:

**Database View**

```
Items
=======================
ID     Name
---    -----
1      Banana 
2      Apple
3      Strawberry
4      Orange


ShopCart_Items
========================================
ItemID    ItemName     CartID     Value
-------   ---------    -------    ------
2         Apple        1          1
4         Orange       1          2
2         Apple        2          2
```

**PageView**
First the repeater is populated with all the items that I have in my 'Items' table and no boxes check or anything.

Then I choose a specific cart (say cartId = 1) to edit, and here's what I'm really confused on how to do:
Now the repeater will have like 15-20 items, so I need to access just the items that the user choose on the current cart (cartId = 1) that the user want to edit, so he could know what did he choose and start choose new values, check/uncheck CheckBoxes, etc.

---

I'm sorry for all this long question, but I'm really confused should/can I access each item directly or what logic do you advice me to use ? ..Thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you have mix two different entities in a one repeater - an orders and order items. 
In my opinion the better approach is to place two repeaters onto the page: the first one for displaying orders and the second one for displaying order items for the selected order. This way you may use simple SqlDataSource controls for both repeaters and add a ControlParameter to the datasource used for retrieving order items depending on current order selection in the first repeater.

Comment: Ok I didn't understand u quite well, if you can illustrat your idea with some code that would be great .. and btw how about having a hidden field and on RowDataBinding I get a counter and add 1 to each HiddenField created ? ..Sorry for my late but I have some work issues =)